# Enviar dados para upload de imagens pelo ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#oformulario").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var nome    = $("#nome").val();
        var email   = $("#email").val();
        var obs     = $("#obs").val();
        var file0   = $("#file0").val();
        var file1   = $("#file1").val();

        if( (nome == "" || nome == null) || 
            (email == "" || email == null) ||   
            (file0 == "" || file0 == null) ){

            alert("Preencha todos os campos obrigatórios.");
            return false;

        } else {

            // Ajax

        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Quero enviar o #file0 e #file1 que são arquivos `(input[type=file])` pelo ajax para o PHP.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na seção de envio de arquivo com o `FormData`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects. O `FormData` pertence ao `XMLHttpRequest 2` e a tabela de versões de browsers que dão suporte está aqui: http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2 (em especial IE8 e IE9 não dão suporte).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aproveitando o `FormData` já referido pelo @Wakim, e como estás usando jQuery, só tens que usar `$.ajax` dentro da tua condição.

Exemplo do $.ajax:

```
var dados = new FormData(this);
var url = "url/para/postUpload.php";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data:  dados,
    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
             // Em caso de sucesso faz isto...
        },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            // Em caso de erro
        }          
    });
```