# Enviar imagem com ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando receber uma imagem no PHP enviada através do AJAX, porém não tive sucesso. Segue o código:

**jQuery:**

```
$("#envmsg").submit(function() {
    $("#btn-enviarmsg").button("loading");
    $("body").css("cursor", "wait");

    var dados = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/enviamsg.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("envmsg").reset();
            $("#btn-enviarmsg").button("reset");
            $("body").css("cursor", "default");
            $("#deixarMensagem").modal("hide");
            location.reload();
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

e no **enviamsg.php** eu faço a verificação:

```
if($_FILES["foto"]) {
        $foto = echo "<script>alert('tem foto');</script>";
    } else {
        $foto = echo "<script>alert('n tem foto');</script>";
    }
```

Porém nada occore, por que?

**Obs.: Este formulário envia alguns campos de texto e a imagem. Apenas postei trechos do código relacionado ao problema.**

**Obs².: Meu formulário está com enctype="multipart/form-data"**.

**Obrigado!**

Comment: Não seria o mesmo que esta pergunta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29770/

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado @Bacco, eu havia feito várias pesquisas, porém ainda não havia visto essa do link que vc me passou. Pois bem, funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: De qualquer forma, a sua pergunta servirá de link para a outra, aumentando a chance de alguém com o mesmo problema encontrar a solução ao pesquisar.